# Legend of a raster map with categorical data

Tags: r, dictionary, legend, raster, categorical-data

I would like to plot a raster containing 4 different values ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpk2q.png)) with a categorical text legend describing the categories such as [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIVOW.png) but with colour boxes:

I've tried using legend such as :

```
legend( 1,-20,legend = c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers","water bodies"))
```

but I don't know how to associate one value to the displayed color. Is there a way to retrieve the colour displayed with 'plot' and to use it in the legend?

[image: Initial raster]

[image: Raster with legend]

Comment: Cross-posted: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73143/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The **rasterVis** package includes a `Raster` method for `levelplot()`, which plots categorical variables and produces an appropriate legend:

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)

## Example data
r <- raster(ncol=4, nrow=2)
r[] <- sample(1:4, size=ncell(r), replace=TRUE)
r <- as.factor(r)

## Add a landcover column to the Raster Attribute Table
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat[["landcover"]] <- c("land","ocean/lake", "rivers","water bodies")
levels(r) <- rat

## Plot
levelplot(r, col.regions=rev(terrain.colors(4)), xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By default, the colours used in a raster-plot are generated by `rev(terrain.colors())` (see `?raster::plot`). You can use this to re-create that sequence of 4 colours for your legend - or choose a random sequence of colours:

```
my_col = rev(terrain.colors(n = 4))
# my_col = c('beige','red','green','blue')
```

First plot the map using the colour sequence. `legend = FALSE` gets rid of the standard colour bar:

```
plot(my_raster, legend = FALSE, col = my_col)
```

Add a custom legend to the bottom left. Use the `fill` argument to generate coloured boxes:

```
legend(x='bottomleft', legend = c("land", "ocean/lake", "rivers", "water bodies"), fill = my_col)
```