# How to plot a TIFF file with categorical legend when downloaded from a website in R?

Tags: r, raster, tiff

Currently I am trying to plot a tiff file available in this website https://visibleearth.nasa.gov/view.php?id=76695.

However, when I plot it in R, the legend totally changes. It does not show forests, shrubs, grasses, crops and cities. The legend shows numbers.

How can I get the correct legend in R as it is shown in .png format of that file in the link mentioned above?

Secondly, I crop and mask the tif file to my area of interest that is the Hindu Kush Himalayan region ( shapefile freely available on http://rds.icimod.org/Home/DataDetail?metadataId=3924) the colour scheme is totally messed up.

How can I get the tif file to look exactly as the .png image provided in the website?

My source is as follows:

```
tif1<-"global_lcc_goodes_lrg.tif"
tif2=raster(tif1)
plot(tif2)
crop1<-crop(tif2,mountains)
mask1<-mask(crop1, mountains)
plot(crop1)`
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi Hal. Welcome to SO. Please limit your post to one question at the time. For the second question use another post.

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19136330/legend-of-a-raster-map-with-categorical-data) may be useful to you.